# Memory Leakage in a long run C++ application

Tags: c++, memory, dictionary, memory-leaks, deque

I am running a long run C++ application which allocates different objects and store it in several deque and maps,and deallocate these object from these data structures at a time.I'm experiencing a small amount of increase in memory(generally 1 mb to 2 mb) day by day.I have run memory leakage detector(valgrind),but i could'nt find any suspicious memory leakage.
I was wondering whether the problem is with the deque and maps where the objects are stored.
Whether the memory of deque and map releases the memory to OS as soon as object is popped from the data structures?
Can anyone please point out solutions or general possible cause for the increase in memory?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not the count of objects that's ever increasing? That is, did you check the size of all of your containers?

Comment: When you remove items from a container the container does not deallocate the memory. So the containers keep whatever memory they needed at their largest capacity. If you want to free the memory you have to explicitly move the data to a fresh container.

Comment: Yes,I have checked the size of the containers.The size have been in a constant range,ie,as one object is popped from it,another is being pushed to the data structures.The count of the object have been in the range (25,000 to 25,050).

Comment: @Galik that comment is wrong. It's true of vector but not of other containers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ standard provides no guarantees that delete will release memory to the OS. In fact many standard C++ libraries do not do this. If you want memory to be released to the OS then you will have to use your OS's own memory allocation routines.

Standard C++ library provides custom allocators which might help you do this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment,but i'm using malloc for allocating memory and free for deallocating memory.Would deque and map releases its memory when a object is popped from it?.Can you suggest any possible cause for increase in memory?

Comment: `malloc` and `free` in a C++ program ? What about `new` and [`std::unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) ?

Comment: What makes you think that free returns memory to the operating system? I've already suggested a reason, not sure I have anything to add.

Comment: I have overrided new operator to invoke malloc.

Comment: Again, what makes you think that free returns memory to the operating system. In general it doesn't.

Comment: Your confusion seems to be over what release means. C and C++ only guarantee that released memory is available again to the program that released it. They do not guarantee that it is available to other programs.

Comment: Handling memory in the way you want to is a tricky task. It requires good knowledge of how your operating system manages memory. You are expecting too much of C or C++ libraries, which are designed for more typical use cases, and of the C and C++ languages which are agnostic about OS issues.

Comment: Thanks John for your valuable suggestions.Well if i free the object the memory of the programs will remain the same,right?But in my case,there is a increase in memory of the program day by day.I was wondering whether the data structures(containers) do not release their memory(when the object is popped from the container) to the program?

Comment: Map does release its memory when popped. I'm fairly sure (but not 100% certain) that deque does too.

Comment: Having looked it up I now believe that deque also releases memory, 'The storage of a deque is automatically expanded and contracted as needed.' from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque

Answer (score 1):

You might run into heap fragmentation.

If you allocate memory blocks of different sizes, it could mean that large memory blocks are eventually divided into smaller blocks and become unusable. For example:

- you allocate one large block (say 1 MB) and the runtime gets that from the OS
- you `free`the large block
- you allocate a smaller block and `malloc` chops that off the freed 1 MB block
- you try to allocate a 1 MB block again, but  the `free`'d one is no longer big enough, so the runtime requests a new 1 MB block from the OS

If this goes on for days, you might end up with lots of free 0.99 MB blocks but the runtime will still have to get a new 1 MB block from the OS each time it is needed.